# Why can this nonlinear instance not be solved by the QF_NRA solver, but can be solved by the default solver?

Tags: z3

The following SMT2 instance can be solved (it is UNSAT), but if I use the `qfnra` solver, the result is unknown.

```
(declare-fun NONDET_INT_32_1 () Int)
(declare-fun lv_n_1_1 () Int)
(declare-fun lv_n_8_1 () Bool)
(declare-fun lv_n_9_1 () Int)
(declare-fun lv_n_10_1 () Bool)
(declare-fun lv_n_18_1 () Bool)
(declare-fun lv_n_19_1 () Int)
(declare-fun lv_n_15_1 () Real)
(declare-fun lv_n_14_1 () Int)
(assert (and true
     (not (distinct lv_n_19_1 0))
     (= lv_n_14_1 (* lv_n_1_1 lv_n_1_1))
     (= lv_n_15_1 (to_real lv_n_14_1))
     (= lv_n_18_1 (distinct (- lv_n_15_1 2.0) 0.0))
     (= lv_n_19_1 (ite lv_n_18_1 1 0))
     lv_n_10_1
     (= lv_n_9_1 (ite lv_n_8_1 1 0))
     (= lv_n_10_1 (distinct lv_n_9_1 0))
     (= lv_n_8_1 (<= lv_n_1_1 10))
     (>= lv_n_1_1 (- 10))
     (= lv_n_1_1 NONDET_INT_32_1)
     ))
;(check-sat-using (then simplify sat qfnra))
(check-sat)
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem does not lie in the `QF_NRA` logic, because your problem contains integers.  The line `(check-sat-using (then simplify sat qfnra))` would force `Z3` to use only the `simplify`, `sat`, and `qfnra` tactics.  If you just write `(check-sat)`, Z3 will use its built-in `default` tactic, which applies multiple preprocessing steps, and then uses the most powerful applicable solver.

Certain problems involving integers can indeed be proven unsat by the `qfnra` solver, because if there are no real numbers that satisfy a given formula, then there are also no integers that satisfy that formula, given that integers are a subset of the reals.  However, this is a specialized situation, and evidently your formula does not fall into this category.

Often, you will get the best result by using the default tactic in Z3, so your result is not surprising to me.  You can use the default tactic by using `(check-sat)`, or by `(check-sat-using default)` if you want to combine it with other specialized tactics.